# How to make font commands like \mathbf not apply to numbers

Tags: fonts

I have a macro that takes an argument and bolds it (in addition to some other things). But I would like it not to bold the numbers.

For example, what I have right now is something like

```
\newcommand{\mybold}{\mathbf}
```

and `\mybold{R^2}` gives

[image]

but what I want is for `\mybold{R^2}` to give

[image]

where the "2" is not bolded.

How can I do that?

Comment: `\mybold{R}^2`?

Comment: @karlkoeller: Too easy ;-)

Comment: @karlkoeller: yea no. I'd want the code as written but have it displayed as pictured.

Comment: It is doubtless possible - egreg has just done it. But why do you want your code to not reflect your output. such a mismatch is misleading and against LaTeX's philosophy

Answer (score 2):

Change (locally) the math code of the digits.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mybold}[1]{\mathbf{\fixnumbers\relax#1}}
\newcommand{\fixnumbers}{%
  \fixnumber{0}%
  \fixnumber{1}%
  \fixnumber{2}%
  \fixnumber{3}%
  \fixnumber{4}%
  \fixnumber{5}%
  \fixnumber{6}%
  \fixnumber{7}%
  \fixnumber{8}%
  \fixnumber{9}%
}
\newcommand{\fixnumber}[1]{\mathcode`#1=\numexpr\mathcode`#1-"7000\relax}

\begin{document}
$\mybold{R^2}+2-\mathbf{3}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
    \setmathfont{xits-mathbold.otf}[version=mybold,range={"0020-"002A,"003A-"FFFF}]
    \newcommand\mybold[1]{{\mathversion{mybold}#1}}
    \begin{document}
        $\mybold{R^2}+2-\mathbf{3}$
    \end{document}
```

[image]

The `R` must be in `\mathit`. However, if you do not like it you canchange it to `\mathup`

Comment: `LaTeX Font Warning: Command \mathversion invalid in math mode on input line 7.` Indeed, I recalled about `\mathversion` being forbidden in math mode. Package `bm` must go through complicated patches to bolden individual symbols.

Comment: Naturally, the code seems to go through, however does `LuaLaTeX` or  `XeLaTeX` document one can use `\mathversion` this way with no after-effects ?